# Rust Lettre send an insecure email

Tags: rust, smtp, smtpclient

I have a mail server that doesn't require auth. I have been using [lettre](https://docs.rs/crate/lettre/latest)

I followed there examples and tried to specify the port to 25, without passing creds. But it still fails with a timeout connecting to server. I believe that's because `relay` forces tls of some kind

```rust
    let tls = TlsParameters::builder("smtp.example.com".to_string())
        .dangerous_accept_invalid_certs(true)
        .dangerous_accept_invalid_hostnames(true)
        .build()
        .unwrap();
    let mailer = SmtpTransport::relay("smtp.example.com")
    .unwrap()
    .tls(Tls::Required(tls))
    .port(25)
    .build();
```

It shouldn't be using tls at all, but I don't know how to turn it off.

Is that possible or do I need a different crate

Comment: _"But it still fails."_ Fails how? Does it fail to compile? Give an error at runtime?

Comment: Updated my post to be more clear

Comment: _"I believe that's because `relay` forces tls of some kind ... It shouldn't be using tls at all, but I don't know how to turn it off."_ You're explicitly turning TLS _on_ with `.tls(Tls::Required(tls))`. Seems like you should be using `.tls(Tls::None)` if you want to disable TLS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lettre has its own function for insecure mail servers. Use [`builder_dangerous`](https://docs.rs/lettre/0.10.0-alpha.2/lettre/transport/smtp/struct.SmtpTransport.html#method.builder_dangerous). Per the docs:

> Creates a new SMTP client
>
> Defaults are:
>
> - No authentication
> - No TLS
> - A 60 seconds timeout for smtp commands
> - Port 25

Here's an example of what it would look like

```rust
    let mailer = SmtpTransport::builder_dangerous("smtp.example.com")
        .build();
```

Note that you can still build off of this and specify port, tls, and authentication.